# Setting order of strings appended to a textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am adding values from a select input element to a textarea. How can I then add conditions to this so that if a certain option value is selected, it is always added at the end of all others?

**HTML**

```
<p>
    <select name="selectfield" id="selectfield">
        <option value="" selected>- Select -</option>
        <option value="HTML/">HTML/</option>
        <option value="CSS/">CSS/</option>
        <option value="JQUERY/">JQUERY/</option>
    </select>
</p>

<textarea style="width:100%" name="info" id="info" cols="20" rows="5"></textarea>
```

**jQuery**

```
$("#selectfield").on("change", function() {
    var $select = $(this);
    $("#info").val(function(i, val) {
        return val += $select.val();
    })
});
```

In this example, I would like "HTML/" to always be at the end of the textarea regardless of when it is selected.

**[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/rdawkins/m7scekvq/1/)**

Comment: Well you need to somehow loop over the collection different...

Comment: I agree with you regarding the bad UX design. Since the textarea is not hidden, the user can simply erase the appended value from the textarea. But yes, I would need to come up with a better solution if the project went live at any stage.

Comment: Can I somehow use Regex to search for "HTML/" and if found, add it to the end? I am not sure how to go about it though.

Comment: I am not fully understanding the behavior you want to achieve. Can there be the same option several times? If I select HTML then JQUERY then HTML then CSS what should I come up with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you set the textarea's value, compare what the value of the select is. If it is the string you want to be added at the end, then add it to the end of the value otherwise add it at the beginning.

```
if($select.val()==="HTML/")
    return val = val + $select.val();
else
    return val = $select.val() + val;
```

https://jsfiddle.net/qshcr01a/

Comment: Elegant! Works perfectly :) Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Above is smarter but this also works:

```
$("#selectfield").on("change", function() {
    var $select = $(this);
    $("#info").val(function(i, val) {
    if (val=="HTML/"){
        return $select.val()+"HTML/";
      }else{
       if(val=="JQUERY/HTML/"){
        return "CSS/JQUERY/HTML/";
        }else if (val=="CSS/HTML/"){
        return "JQUERY/CSS/HTML/";
        }else{
         return val+= $select.val()
        }
      }
    })
});
```